# Cherry Framework "Font Awesome" issue on secure site

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl

I am setting up an eCommerce site using a theme I bought off of Template Monster.  The child theme uses the Cherry Framework as the parent theme.

I purchased an SSL cert and had it installed on my server and am redirecting all non-HTTPS requests to HTTPS via the .htaccess file.

All browsers are saying that insecure content is being loaded, and asks me if I want to proceed.  The culprit being the Cherry Framework is linking to the Font Awesome source at an "http" source.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css', false, '3.2.1', 'all' );
```

The file that this piece of code is in is:

```
CherryFramework/includes/theme-scripts.php

function cherry_stylesheets() {
if ( CURRENT_THEME != 'cherry' ) {
    if ( file_exists( CHILD_DIR . '/main-style.css' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( CURRENT_THEME, CHILD_URL . '/main-style.css', false, null, 'all' );
    }

    if ( file_exists( CHILD_DIR . '/includes/widgets/my-flickr-widget.php' ) ) {
        wp_register_style( 'prettyPhoto', PARENT_URL.'/css/prettyPhoto.css', false, '3.1.5', 'all' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'prettyPhoto' );
    }
}
wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', 'http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css', false, '3.2.1', 'all' );
wp_register_style( 'magnific-popup', PARENT_URL.'/css/magnific-popup.css', false, '0.9.3', 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'magnific-popup' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cherry_stylesheets');
```

I updated that line of code to point to the https source file.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', 'https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css', false, '3.2.1', 'all' );
```

I FTP'd the updated file to the server, and it overwrites the file.

However, when I refresh the page, the source code shows that is it still linking to the file at the http source.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='font-awesome-css'  href='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css?ver=3.2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

I don't have any Wordpress caching plugins installed.  I have also cleared my browser cache numerous times.

Anyone have any idea why the updated file will not render the correct source code?

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='font-awesome-css'  href='https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css?ver=3.2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Comment: Did you try preceeding the address only with //? something like "href='//netdna...."

Comment: Yes, no luck with that either.  It still renders the HTTP source.  I even tried removing that line of code all together, and the site still renders the line of code.  I am beyond dumbfounded as to how that is even possible,

Comment: I copied both the parent and child theme folders to my desktop and did a Find All in Dreamweaver for that specific http URL, and the only place I found it is was the theme-scripts.php file.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?  I had the same issue - and was able to fix it.

Comment: The only way I was able to resolve it was to keep the site as http and enable the option to force SSL on the checkout page within the WooCommerce settings.

How did you end up fixing it, because I would like to be able to redirect all http requests to https!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this problem, you have two choices.  You can update the style reference to use HTTPS or you can copy the solution locally if you have a project that has issues reaching netdna.bootstrapcdn.com due to firewall restrictions for example.

### Solution 1:

1. Deregister font-awesome from Parent theme via your child theme functions.php file as outlined below.

```php
function yourScriptsAndStyles() {  
    wp_deregister_style( 'font-awesome' );      
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', 'https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css', false, '3.2.1', 'all' );   
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourScriptsAndStyles' );
```

### Solution 2:

(NOTE: This copies Font-Awesome locally, so to apply any Font-Awesome updates in the future, you'll need to update your copy of Font-Awesome )

1. Download a copy of font-awesome from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/
2. Extract zip and into your child theme
3. Deregister font-awesome from Parent theme via your child theme functions.php file as outlined below.

```php
function yourScriptsAndStyles() {  
    wp_deregister_style( 'font-awesome' );      
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/font-awesome-4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css', false, '4.0.3', 'all' );  
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourScriptsAndStyles' );
```